# How to fix the error object is possibly undefined using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to fix the error "object is possibly undefined" using react and typescript

below is my code,

```
const App = () => {
    const {data, loading } = useQuery<SomeQuery>;
    const types = React.useMemo(() => {
        const types = data.main?.types ?? []; //i get error here
    },[data]);

    return (
        {types && types !== null && !isEmpty(types) 
            ? type.map(type => 
                <div>{type.name}</div>
            ) : undefined
        }
    );
}
```

as seen from above code, i get error in useMemo near data.main

i am not sure how to fix this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell TypeScript that the data variable may be undefined too:

```
const types = data?.main?.types ?? [];
```

Comment: thanks i have added the change and now it says object is possibly null when i map types in the return